# Debian -> Setting up HDMI input port on laptop to send the screen to TV

Tags: debian, hdmi

What I would like to do is connect my laptop, which has Debian 9 installed, to the TV using HDMI cable. Currently, when I go to the Displays section, I only have one available, and that is the display of my laptop.

I need to configure the HDMI to send both video and audio from laptop to the TV.

I am certain HDMI port works since I also have Windows on this laptop and there are no problems there.

Edit: this is the setup I have:
Asus VivoBook
AMD CPU Ryzen5
with AMD Vega 5 graphics card.
Edit: I've also found this information: 03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15dd (rev c4) which I got using lspci | grep VGA.

Comment: Could you add hardware details (e.g., laptop make/model) and display driver if you know it?

Comment: I've edited the question, and added these information:
Asus VivoBook AMD CPU Ryzen5 with AMD Vega 5 graphics card.